How can I get Johansen cointegration between time series data in Python?
I'm trying to figure out the Johansen cointegration between several time series using statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen.
I checked all the variables are I(1) series and run the code
coint_johansen(dataframe, det_order = 1, k_ar_diff = 3) 

to include deterministic time trend in the model.
Finally, I got the result implying that there's one significant cointegration between variables, but I want to figure out the exact expression with coefficients.
For example, let X_t, Y_t: time series variables.
Then the final expression I want to figure out is (a,b,c,d are constants)something like
a * X_t + b * Y_t + ... + c * t + d = (stationary I(0) process)
How can I get the desired result?
